# Show that for every $s \in \mathbb{N}$, $s \geq 2$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, $\lim\limits_{x \longrightarrow \ a} \sqrt[s]{x} = \sqrt[s]{a}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

The proof will be divided into two parts. In the first part, we will prove the case a = 0. Then, in the second part, we will prove the case a > 0.

1. Suppose a = 0. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of $(0, \infty)$ such that $x_n \longrightarrow 0$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$n > n_0 \ \Rightarrow \ \mid x_n - a \mid \ < \ \varepsilon^s.$$

Follow thats

$$n > n_0 \ \Rightarrow \ \sqrt[s]{x_n} \ = \ \mid \sqrt[s]{x_n} - 0 \mid \ < \ \sqrt[s]{\varepsilon^s} \ = \ \varepsilon. $$

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x \longrightarrow \ 0}  \sqrt[s]{x} = 0$.

2. Suppose a > 0. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of $[0, \infty) - \{a\}$ such that $x_n \longrightarrow a$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$n > n_0 \ \Rightarrow \ \mid x_n - a \mid \ < \ \varepsilon\sqrt[s]{a^{s-1}}.$$

Note that

$$x_n - a = (\sqrt[s]{x_n} - \sqrt[s]{a})(\sqrt[s]{x_{n}^{s - 1}} + \sqrt[s]{x_n^{s - 2}}\sqrt[s]{a} + ... + \sqrt[s]{x_n}\sqrt[s]{a^{s - 2}} + \sqrt[s]{a^{s-1}}).$$

Realize that

$$\sqrt[s]{a^{s-1}} \ \leq \ \sqrt[s]{x_{n}^{s - 1}} + \sqrt[s]{x_n^{s - 2}}\sqrt[s]{a} + ... + \sqrt[s]{x_n}\sqrt[s]{a^{s - 2}} + \sqrt[s]{a^{s-1}} \ \Rightarrow \ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[s]{x_{n}^{s - 1}} + \sqrt[s]{x_n^{s - 2}}\sqrt[s]{a} + ... + \sqrt[s]{x_n}\sqrt[s]{a^{s - 2}} + \sqrt[s]{a^{s-1}}} \ \leq \ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[s]{a^{s-1}}}.  $$

Then

$$n > n_0 \ \Rightarrow \ \mid x_n - a \mid \ \cdot \ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[s]{x_{n}^{s - 1}} + \sqrt[s]{x_n^{s - 2}}\sqrt[s]{a} + ... + \sqrt[s]{x_n}\sqrt[s]{a^{s - 2}} + \sqrt[s]{a^{s-1}}}  $$

$$ = \dfrac{\mid x_n - a \mid}{\sqrt[s]{x_{n}^{s - 1}} + \sqrt[s]{x_n^{s - 2}}\sqrt[s]{a} + ... + \sqrt[s]{x_n}\sqrt[s]{a^{s - 2}} + \sqrt[s]{a^{s-1}}} \ = \ \mid \sqrt[s]{x_n} - \sqrt[s]{a} \mid  \ < \ \dfrac{\varepsilon\sqrt[s]{a^{s-1}}}{\sqrt[s]{a^{s-1}}} = \varepsilon.$$

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x \longrightarrow \ a}  \sqrt[s]{x} = \sqrt[s]{a}$. Then we finish the proof.

It's true?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info Assuming that "It's true?" meant "Is my proof correct?", I added the tag solution-verification. But "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough." This site is not meant as an automatic proof-checker.